# Select all fields where fieldone is not equal to null + Propel

Tags: php, mysql, pear, propel, phing

I have a question about using the propel ORM and creating a query.

I have a table **"locations"** with fields:

> - location
> - sublocation
> - postcode
> - street
> - number

Now I want to select all the locations where the location field **IS NOT** equal to 'null'.
How can I do this? I've tried this but I get back all the results ...

Tried query: `$locations = LocationQuery::create()->where('location' != null)->find();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know propel.  But the proper SQL syntax for the expression would be:

```
$locations = LocationQuery::create()->where('location is not null')->find();
```

Any comparison to `NULL` in SQL returns `NULL`, which is treated as false. With the exception of `is null` and `is not null`.

Comment: Thanks! The right syntax was: locations = LocationQuery::create()->where('location IS NOT NULL')->find();

Answer (score 24):

You can use this:

```
->filterByColumnName(null, Criteria::NOT_EQUAL)
```

There are various 'Criteria' uses in propel, listed here: [propel criteria](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html)

There isn't an exact sample for this on the site, the closest is this:

```
->filterByTags(array('novel', 'russian'), Criteria::CONTAINS_NONE)
```

Comment: This is the 'Correct Propel' way

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
->filterByColumnName(null, CRITERIA::ISNOTNULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference all of the Propel 2 comparison types for `CRITERIA::_needed_type_` [here](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/blob/master/src/Propel/Runtime/ActiveQuery/Criteria.php).

```
EQUAL
NOT_EQUAL
ALT_NOT_EQUAL
GREATER_THAN
LESS_THAN
GREATER_EQUAL
LESS_EQUAL
LIKE
NOT_LIKE
CONTAINS_ALL
CONTAINS_SOME
CONTAINS_NONE
ILIKE
NOT_ILIKE
CUSTOM
RAW
CUSTOM_EQUAL
DISTINCT
IN
NOT_IN
ALL
JOIN
BINARY_AND
BINARY_OR
ASC
DESC
ISNULL
ISNOTNULL
CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_TIME
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
LEFT_JOIN
RIGHT_JOIN
INNER_JOIN
LOGICAL_OR
LOGICAL_AND
```